# Balancear parentesis y resolver una operación aritmética sin usar eval() ni funciones similares en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algoritmos

Intento resolver este problema. he logrado balancear los paréntesis de la operación aritmética, pero mi calculo de la operación está incorrecta, no sé como mejorar mi algoritmo. Por favor ayuda.

Ejemplos de entrada y salida

- **`(16+4)/5-{5+8}*[1-2] → 17`**
- **`5*9-3+{2-1}*(9-[24/8]) → 48`**
- **`[{(15-5)*5}/2]+(8-2)*{25+2} → 187`**
- **`{3+5}*2/(4+4)+0*(-68+25 → Syntax Error`**

Mi código:

```
"use strict";
class Calculator {
  //.replace(/[{[]/g,'(').replace(/[}\]]/g,')')
  constructor(exp) {
    this.exp = exp;
  }
  evaluate() {
    let stack = new Array();
    //we check the parenthesis balance
    for (let i = 0; i < this.exp.length; i++) {
      if (
        this.exp[i] == "(" ||
        this.exp[i] == "{" ||
        this.exp[i] == "[" ||
        this.exp[i] == ")" ||
        this.exp[i] == "}" ||
        this.exp[i] == "]" ||
        /^[0-9]/.test(this.exp[i]) ||
        this.exp[i] == "+" ||
        this.exp[i] == "-" ||
        this.exp[i] == "*" ||
        this.exp[i] == "/"
      ) {
        if (this.exp[i] == "(" || this.exp[i] == "{" || this.exp[i] == "[")
          stack.push(this.exp[i]);
        else {
          if (this.exp[i] == ")") {
            if (stack.pop() != "(") return "Syntax Error";
          } else {
            if (this.exp[i] == "]") {
              if (stack.pop() != "[") return "Syntax Error";
            } else {
              if (this.exp[i] == "}") {
                if (stack.pop() != "{") return "Syntax Error";
              }
            }
          }
        }
      } else {
        return 'Invalid character: "' + this.exp[i] + '"';
      }
    }
    if (stack.length == 0) {
      return this.calculate();
    } else return "Syntax Error";
  }
  //Method to calculate an operation
  operationStringtoNumber(fn) {
    return new Function("return " + fn)();
  }
  //Priority of operations
  calculate() {
    let op = "",
      operation = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.exp.length; i++) {
      if (this.exp[i] == "(" || this.exp[i] == "{" || this.exp[i] == "[") {
        for (let j = i; j < this.exp.length; j++) {
          if (
            /^[0-9]/.test(this.exp[j]) ||
            this.exp[j] == "+" ||
            this.exp[j] == "-" ||
            this.exp[j] == "*" ||
            this.exp[j] == "/"
          ) {
            op += this.exp[j];
          } else if (
            this.exp[j] == ")" ||
            this.exp[j] == "}" ||
            this.exp[j] == "]"
          ) {
            //console.log(op);
            operation = this.operationStringtoNumber(op);
            if (this.exp.indexOf("{" + op + "}") > -1)
              this.exp = this.exp.replace("{" + op + "}", operation);
            if (this.exp.indexOf("(" + op + ")") > -1)
              this.exp = this.exp.replace("(" + op + ")", operation);
            if (this.exp.indexOf("[" + op + "]") > -1)
              this.exp = this.exp.replace("[" + op + "]", operation);
            //console.log(operation, this.exp);
            op = "";
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    //Last operations and get result.
    if (this.exp.indexOf("{") > -1) {
      this.exp = this.exp.replace("{", "");
      this.exp = this.exp.replace("}", "");
    } else if (this.exp.indexOf("(") > -1) {
      this.exp = this.exp.replace("(", "");
      this.exp = this.exp.replace(")", "");
    } else if (this.exp.indexOf("[") > -1) {
      this.exp = this.exp.replace("[", "");
      this.exp = this.exp.replace("]", "");
    }
    this.exp = this.operationStringtoNumber(this.exp);
    return this.exp;
  }
}
//READ file
const readline = require("readline"),
  fs = require("fs"),
  file = "files/exp.txt";

let reader = readline.createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream(file),
});

reader.on("line", (line) => {
  let c = new Calculator(line);
  //console.log(c.operationStringtoNumber(line.replace(/[{[]/g,'(').replace(/[}\]]/g,')')));
  console.log(c.evaluate());
});
```

En general funciona pero no para todos los casos, este es un feedback que me dieron y me gustaría aprender a resolver este ejercicio de manera óptima.

Carece de lógica que valide casos bordes, permite división entre cero, no permite casos como **`(1+2)*-(2+3)`** entre otras. Complejidad ciclomática muy alta, hay demasiados *For* anidado con muchos condicionales *If* en cada uno de ellos.

Comment: ¿Estás siguiendo algún algoritmo para resolver el problema? Recuerdo que cuando iba a la escuela me pusieron un problema similar, a modo de caso de estudio de [Big Endian y Little Endian](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-is-endianness-big-endian-vs-little-endian/). Claro, no está directamente relacionado pero te puede ayudar para cómo leer toda tu cadena de operación.

Comment: Como sugerencia ppodría decirte que no prestes mucha atención al orden en el que se encuntran las llaves, paréntesis y demás. Recorres uno a uno y vas guarando cada uno de los valores en arrays diferentes y luego evaluas que tengas un número par de "divisiones" (los signos que separan los grupos), de no ser así, pudes deducir que falta uno y con ello cubres el último caso. Dependiendo de cómo hayas decicido recorrer la cadena, puedes ir formando y reduciendo los grupos para dar con el resultado.

Comment: Las pilas son las estructuras de datos ideales para balancear paréntesis

Comment: Entra aquí https://runestone.academy/runestone/static/pythoned/BasicDS/ParentesisSimplesBalanceados.html

Comment: @Japv El balanceo de paréntesis esta ok, lo que me acompleja mas es resolver la operación aritmética.

Comment: @ricardo-dlc La verdad no se me ocurre que algoritmo usar para ir calculando la operación aritmética en el orden correcto. Leyendo tu sugerencia, se me viene a la mente usar una tabla de hash quizás o algo así... no tengo clara la idea.

Comment: Tal vez la [notación posfija](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notaci%C3%B3n_polaca_inversa) (o notación polaca inversa) pueda ayudarte, y está muy relacionada con las pilas como menciona el compañero @Japv

Comment: Realice un trabajo similar(o el mismo) en la universidad, esto fue para **automatas** dicho proyecto fue solo una introducción para realizar un analizador de código, para realizar tu lógica, tienes que realizar un **diagrama de sintaxis**.
aquí encuentras un ejemplo muy claro. [**Diagrama sintáctico para expresiones aritméticas.**](http://lenguajesyautomatas1unidad6-4.blogspot.com/2016/06/diagramas-de-sintaxis.html)

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda @ricardo-dlc, intentare resolverlo nuevamente.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Richard por tu aporte!

Comment: Entra aquí http://acodigo.blogspot.com/2013/02/evaluador-de-expresiones-matematicas.html?m=1

Comment: @Japv Muchas gracias!